# Laravel 4 mongodb profiler / query log

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-4

Does anybody know if there is a way to profile or log mongodb queries in laravel 4 ?

I'm actually using https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB as driver.

Default profiler is DB::getQueryLog() but seems to not be working with that driver.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Query logging support has been added to the package recently. Get the newest version and it should work.